# Sending input values to webpage using urllib2 in python

Tags: python, html, urllib2

I am trying to get the similarity score between two sets of GO terms, there is a [webpage](http://bioinformatics.clemson.edu/G-SESAME/tools.php?id=3) that does it and I am trying to automate this calculation for several sets using a python script.
So far from my script I generate two files that if uploaded manually work to the webpage, but I cannot figure out how to do it from the code.

```
temp1 = somefile
url = "http://bioinformatics.clemson.edu/G-SESAME/tools.php?id=3"
isa = "0.8"
partof = "0.6"
for f_set in features_set_list:
    temp2 = open('temp2.txt', "w")
    for item in f_set:
        print >> temp2, item + '\t'
    temp2.close()

    values = {"tool_id":"3","uploadedfile1": temp1,"uploadedfile2": temp2,"isA": isa,"partOf": partof,"email":"False" ,"emailAddress": "","description": "","submit": "Submit"}
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    html = response.read()
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    score = root.cssselect("div.row span b")[0].text
    print score
```

My guess is that my error is in the values that give as input, but cannot find it. Any help would be appreciated!